# Spatial interpolation of vectors in vector fields

Tags: spatial, interpolation

Statistical modeling is new to me and I would appreciate some thoughts on my project. I am trying to model the spatial (and possibly temporal as well) relationships within vectors in vector fields. Just for the sake of background, each vector field is a collection of motion vectors that corresponds to a compressed HD video frame. When video gets corrupted, some vectors are lost and I am attempting to recover them via interpolation using a spatial (or, even better, spatial-temporal) model that captures the spatial relationships among vectors.

See the link below for examples of what motion vectors look like within video frames.
http://blog.prashanthellina.com/2008/03/30/visualizing-mpeg4-motion-compensation-vectors-using-mplayer/

What are some thoughts on a viable direction to pursue? So far, kriging seems most promising, but I've also looked at CAR and SAR.

Comment: Did you find an answer to this question?

Comment: @dev_nut No, not really. But I ended up simply using some sort of k-nearest neighbors algorithm. Do you have a similar question or some sort of response?

Comment: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/369074/spatio-temporal-interpolation-of-vector-fields , yes, I'm pretty much trying to come up with a way to do a reasonable (meaning smooth) interpolation of a time varying vector field